# Easiest way to delete a million records?

Tags: soql, data-loader, delete

Been doing tests in sandbox in which I've created about a million accountshares that I need to get rid of for testing.

I'm trying data loader in bulk api mode to export than delete but I keep getting:

> InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: QUERY_TIMEOUT: Your query request was running for too long. Trying again later.;

Not sure if I should be waiting longer? Any other options or dataloader configurations I should be looking at?

**EDIT**

I've been trying with batch apex jobs yet still having issues.

**Script**

```
string str='select id from AccountShare where lastmodifiedbyid =\'0050P000007Kfy2\' limit 10000';
sharedeletebatch bdt=new sharedeletebatch(str);
Database.executeBatch(bdt);
system.debug(bdt);
```

**Batch**

```
global class sharedeletebatch Implements Database.batchable<sobject>
{

     global final string query;
     global sharedeletebatch(string q){

          query=q;
     }

     global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
     }
     global  void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<SObject> scope){
         delete scope;

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }


}
```

> First error: [REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped.

Comment: You can write a batch class to delete all of them in a single go.

Comment: Dataloader.io is also a good option, if you want to delete them via configuration.

Comment: any good examples on doing this? I'm not too familiar with batch jobs.

Comment: Is the problem on export or on delete?

Comment: Can do you do an execute anon script? I've never tried it with a million records tho

Comment: Seen this error more recently (last few weeks). Seems an issue in salesforce. You can no longer get a query locator on millions of records without a filter in a batch start or the query will timeout. So a batch of "Select Id From XYZ_Object" will timeout in a batch start now. Adding a Limit to the query will also timeout. I do not believe it was an issue until recently

Comment: i even added a filter of lastmodifiedby which fails.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned in the comments section, it might have been a Salesforce issue which is no longer the case. Exporting that amount of data shouldn't throw a timeout.

Nevertheless, if you would like to stick to the Data Loader, consider modifying (increasing) the following values at [Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configuring_the_data_loader.htm&type=5)):

- batch size (if Bulk API is enabled, the max value is 10000)
- timeout
- query request size (the max value is 2000)

But if there is a need to repeat the process, it will be much easier to get familiar with [Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Usage example:
[What is best way to delete all records from any Dev org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120588/what-is-best-way-to-delete-all-records-from-any-dev-org)